# Multi processing or threads in http service?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I am using Flask to host a http service:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5000/segment?text=this is a test')
```

When a client calls this service, it has to process text one by one. I have 2 questions regarding this:

1) In order to make use of Python's multiprocessings or multithreads, can the client send multi requests concurrently to this http service to speed it up?

2) If it is yes to question 1), does this 'segment' have to support multiprocessing? I can make it use multiprocessing, but the parameters have to a list of text, not a single text.

Generally, in this http service context, how to make the http requests to be processed faster, hopefully both from client and server side (i.e. 'segment' function)?

Answer (score 1):

In production, you won't expose the flask http server to the world. You will expose a Gunicorn interface (uWSGI) which will dispatch several worker threads. You won't need to import multiprocessing and write the logic yourself.

What this means is that if Client A and B send a request at the same time, Gunicorn will dispatch 2 threads to handle both the requests and those threads may return a response when they terminate (for the sake of simplicity, we can say that they return at the same time).

So the answer is yes, the client can send multiple requests synchronously at once. Your server will be able to handle multiple requests if you set up Gunicorn (which is recommended in the Flask docs).

Comment: Hi, justahuman, you mean even if my 'segment' function doesn't support multi- threads or multi-processing, through Gunicorn, multiprocessing is still possible when multiple requests are sent concurrently over http call?  In this case, if a client wants to speed up his request processing, he needs to write multiprocessing codes to be able to send multi-requests to the server, right? If his code is single-threaded or singleprocessing, he can't achieve the speedup. Is that true?

Comment: @marlon What do you mean your function doesn't support multi-threads? Does each thread depend on another? Do you have dead lock conditions that prevent concurrent access? If your answer to these questions is no, then yes, your `segment` function will indeed run in parallel with other requests. Onto the second question, that seems like an inefficient design. You should not rely on the client developing their own logic to run concurrent code on your API. This logic should be embedded in the server side. Requests are IO and the less requests sent, the better.

Comment: Thus, you can change your architecture to accommodate multiple threads on the server side and have the client only send one request. However, this means that you will need to import threading and write the logic yourself. If you face deadlocks, this will help greatly because you can embed logic to avoid this behavior. In terms of design, rather than taking scalar values, you can take in a list of values from the client to operate. This means less requests (IO), server side multi-threading, and less work for the client.

Comment: 1) 'What do you mean your function doesn't support multi-threads? ' I mean my function is single threaded, and no multiprocessing either. 2) 'rather than taking scalar values, you can take in a list of values from the client', how to take a list of values from a url request? I have another function which takes a list of inputs with multiprocessing in python. So this may help. Right?